# Find max/min temperatures from hourly ranging data for each day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having issues developing a formula that can find the max/min temps from a range of hourly temperatures for each day. Fill in each day w/ constant high/low then move on to next day.

[image]

i.e. the High column would be filled with constant 46.04 for 10/1/2019 and then would change to another constant (max temp) for 10/2/2019. Assume column letters as A:K.

edit: I have tried using MAX(IF(MATCH(DATE(YEAR, MONTH, DAY)), range values)). etc. but the window does not slide as desired.

Comment: Look into MAXIFS instead of combining MAX and IF.

Comment: Why not MAXIFS? What does "the window does not slide" mean?

Comment: Ah I meant "window does not slide" thinking of it in terms of a sliding window in python, etc. I.e. the window being each consecutive day and length being 24 hours of every day.

Comment: I am not too familiar with MAXIFS. I've been looking into it a bit - but still running into some problems.

Comment: `=maxifs($C$2:$C$100,$a$2:$a$100,a2)` and copy down ?

Comment: Hi - above worked for the first row but then proceeded to give #VALUE! for all consecutive

Comment: Actually, I left out a $. Seems to be working now. Thanks!

Comment: You can create a Pivot table, but if you need the data inside those two columns then I guess VBA is the solution.